# get rid of extra whitespaces when performing std::regex_replace

Tags: c++, regex

How to get rid of extra whitespaces when performing `std::regex_replace` using back references.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    const std::string str { "https://www.youtube.com\t"
    "http://www.google.com"
    };

    const std::regex reg_pattern { R"((https?://([\w\.?]+)([\s]*)))" };
    std::string res;
    std::regex_replace(std::back_inserter(res), std::begin(str), std::end(str), reg_pattern, "<a href='$1'>$2</a>\n");
    std::cout << res << std::endl;
}
```

This is the output I'm getting

```
<a href='https://www.youtube.com    '>www.youtube.com</a>
<a href='http://www.google.com'>www.google.com</a>
```

I'm trying to get the following output

```
<a href='https://www.youtube.com'>www.youtube.com</a>
<a href='http://www.google.com'>www.google.com</a>
```

Comment: Just modify the reg ex? `R"((https?://([\w\.?]+))([\s]*))"` [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ee9a550f21dbde7)

Comment: Even simpler would be to remove the whitespace match from the regex altogether.

Comment: The simplified regex works for me. `R"(https?://([\w\.?]+))"` with regex_replace `"<a href='$0'>$1</a>\n"`. The matches `$0` are `https://www.youtube.com` and `http://www.google.com`, the first groups `$1` are `www.youtube.com` and `www.google.com`

Comment: @273K the `\t` character gets inserted in the second line https://godbolt.org/z/Mf443q8P6

Comment: Ok, did not expect it. Then `R"((https?://([\w\.?]+))([\s]*))"` works, one parenthesis is moved,  w/o other modifications.

Comment: @273K I'm still not getting why the `\t` character getting inserted though you extracted only `\w[a-zA-Z0-9]` and `.`

Comment: The closing parenthesis of the first group (outer) included `\s`, that eats `\t`. `(smth(smth)\s*)`. `\s*` should be outside the first group `(smth(smth))\s*`.

Comment: @273K I'm talking about about your first comment. why `\t` getting inserted in the second line of the output https://godbolt.org/z/Mf443q8P6 though there is only one group

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
(https?://(\S+))\s*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3dxipk/1). *Details*:

- `(https?://(\S+))` - Group 1: `https://` or `http://` and then one or more non-whitespace chars captured into Group 2
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces.

See the [C++ demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2bc678730438cf6):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    const std::string str { "https://www.youtube.com\t"
    "http://www.google.com"
    };

    const std::regex reg_pattern { R"((https?://(\S+))\s*)" };
    std::string res;
    std::regex_replace(std::back_inserter(res), std::begin(str), std::end(str), reg_pattern, "<a href='$1'>$2</a>\n");
    std::cout << res << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
<a href='https://www.youtube.com'>www.youtube.com</a>
<a href='http://www.google.com'>www.google.com</a>
```